# What is the best practice for handling load when collecting billions of datasets in a .NET No-SQL environment?

Tags: .net, nosql, signalr, asp.net-web-api2, bigdata

I have a new project requirement that will see the collection billions of datasets from different web-sources every week. I have established that a No-SQL storage solution is most appropriate (probably using Apache Spark) but I need to consider the performance and load when receiving and storing these billions of records. All literature and examples I can find for working with No-SQL on large datasets is utilising pre-existing large datasets, so ignoring the problem of *collecting* the data to begin with.

My previous experience has been in SQL Server supported solutions, interfacing through either .NET Web-API or through Signalr. I've not had to deal with anything like the amount of load this will require before.

Please advise as to best practices for **collecting** large datasets and link to any useful resources.